# Swift[String: AnyObject] not convertible to T Swift Arrays

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I am working inside a Swift Extension. I am trying to append data to an array of the type `[[String: AnyObject]]`. The reason that this is in an extension is because I have to do this lot's of times to lot's of arrays. The problem is, when I append an object of type: `[String: AnyObject]`, I get the error: `Dictionary'<'String, AnyObject'>' Not Convertible to T` (the quotes are there because within the carrots nothing showed up).

```
mutating func appendData(data: [String: [String: AnyObject]]?) {
    if data != nil {
        for (id, object) in data! {
            var mutatingObject = object
            mutatingObject["id"] = id
            append(mutatingObject)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "The reason that this is in an extension is because I have to do this lot's of times to lot's of arrays." Note that if you're using `AnyObject` in lots of arrays, you're likely doing something wrong in Swift. `AnyObject` is occasionally necessary, but you should convert these arrays and dictionaries to concrete types (usually structs) as quickly as possible and then work with those. Logic around `AnyObject` and key/value dictionaries tends to get very complicated and error-prone very quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not certain what exactly are you trying to achieve. but take a note - Arrays are generic collections that store specific type. Extension for Array might not know what type will be used in each case, so it cannot simply allow you to store `Dictionary<String, AnyObject>`.

Here is an example on how to make your code more generic:

```
extension Array {
    mutating func appendData(data: [String: T]?) {
        if data != nil {
            for (id, object) in data! {
                if var mutatingObject = object as? [String : AnyObject] {
                    mutatingObject["id"] = id
                }

                append(object)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So does `object` get updated by editing mutatingObject?